# get the value of a point by interpolation in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I need to get the value of temperature in a point (latitude, longitude) using the value of temperature of others points (latitude, longitude) by interpolation... I have the temperature of some stations (for exemple, 10, 40.01, 03.00 ....) in a csv file. 
I want to use only the values inside a radio from my point. How can I do that in R?

Comment: Please can you re-frame your question? Are you interested in 2D interpolation as a mathematical problem? On the sphere, or on the plane, or in a thin spherical shell, or in a spherical shell with a time dimension? If so, try Googling things like "Radial basis function interpolation in R" or "Kriging in R". Or do you want to solve the general atmospheric modelling problem, i.e. come up with a 3 or 4D temperature field that is consistent with observation and physical law? If so, recruit a few hundred scientists, mathematicians and programmers and be prepared to wait a few years for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatial regression is a complex problem. You may get ideas from the CRAN Task: Analysis of Spatial Data

https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=Spatial

Comment: I have solved it, thanks